# GDAL merge problem in Python code

Tags: gdal-merge

I am getting the error while I am trying to stack individual raster bands into one image.

> ValueError: expected array of dim 2

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
os.chdir(r'C:\osgeopy-data\Landsat\Washington')
band1_fn = 'p047r027_7t20000730_z10_nn101.tif'
band2_fn = 'p047r027_7t20000730_z10_nn201.tif'
band3_fn = 'p047r027_7t20000730_z10_nn301.tif'

in_ds = gdal.Open(band1_fn)

in_band = in_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds = gtiff_driver.Create('nat_color.tif',
      in_band.XSize, in_band.YSize, 3, in_band.DataType)
out_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())

in_data = in_band.ReadAsArray()
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(3)

out_band.WriteArray(in_data)
in_ds = gdal.Open(band2_fn)
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(2)

out_band.WriteArray(in_ds.ReadAsArray())


out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(
gdal.Open(band3_fn).ReadAsArray())

out_ds.FlushCache()
for i in range(1, 4):
    out_ds.GetRasterBand(i).ComputeStatistics(False)

out_ds.BuildOverviews('average', [2, 4, 8, 16, 32])
del out_ds
```

Comment: Indicating on which line the error occurs should make this question far more answerable

Comment: I am getting error in  line 24, in <module> out_band.WriteArray(in_ds.ReadAsArray())

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain information requested in comments. Note that there seems to be a line mismatch between the error you're reporting an the code you've provided.

Comment: out_band.WriteArray(in_ds.ReadAsArray()) ->Line 26 i am getting error expected array of dim 2